# Volumetrics don't show through glass

Tags: transparency, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics, glass

[image]

Is it some Eevee limitation or am I doing something wrong ? Here are my SSR and material parameters:

[image] [image]

[image]

Comment: Try putting "refraction depth" to 0 ?

Comment: @Gorgious Same result

Comment: What volume shader are you using ?

Comment: @Gorgious Principled volume imgur.com/zz1ZoDp